# Minimum distance between long curtains and radiator for good air flow?

Tags: thermodynamics, convection

It's a known fact that you cannot place a curtain near a radiator because it will trap hot air behind the curtain and also block cold air from going through the radiator from bellow.

But obviously there must be a minimum distance you can place a curtain that goes from ceiling to floor in front of the radiator that would allow it to do its normal work. What is this distance in centimeters(hopefully) ?

[image]

[image: As you can see the air can go up and to the room from the sides]

[image: I placed the curtains 10 cm in front of the radiator so that it doens't stop airflow, I hope this is good enough]